# Jboss-6.1 Application running very slow

Tags: linux, windows, jboss6.x, java-6

my application is running on jboss 6.1, and after few days my applications runs very slow., this is the situation I am facing every week,. for this I am killing java and clearing the temp and work folders and restarting the jboss again. Is there any other ways to clean the memory / manage the application. Kindly give me the suggestions for Linux and windows platforms.

Kindly help any one.

Thanks & Regards,
Sharath

Answer (score 0):

Based on your RAM size of the system you can increase following parameters in run.conf(for linux) or run.conf.bat(for windows):

XMS, XMX, MaxPermSize.

-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=128M

The flag Xmx specifies the maximum memory allocation pool for a Java Virtual Machine (JVM), while Xms specifies the initial memory allocation pool.

MaxPermSize are used to set size for Permanent Generation
The Permanent Generation is where class files are kept. These are the result of compiled classes and jsp pages. If this space is full, it triggers a Full Garbage Collection. If the Full Garbage Collection cannot clean out old unreferenced classes and there is no room left to expand the Permanent Space, an Out‐of‐ Memory error (OOME) is thrown and the JVM will crash
Hope you are aware of these three flags.